# Asp Classic Wrong Encoding

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I've developed a web site sine 2001 with asp classic and MS SQL Server 
from 2 months ago i accessed my web site and i found that all my database records have a different encoding character, specially the Arabic data , it has unknown encoding character which indicates that the database has been corrupted or something happen However,  there is no Development updates happened  .....
i want to restore my real database with it's arabic data ,
So any one have a solution to fix this problem please feedback . also i scare this problem could spread to all web site developed with Asp classic   ....

Comment: Since you state no modifications to the code occurred obviously the system configuration was changed.

Comment: Did someone change the default encoding of the Database maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your site have been hit by some SQL Injection there are some bots that write javascript to all varchar fields, maybe i could mess up Arabic Data as well.

Here are some tips to prevent the problem:
http://blogs.iis.net/nazim/archive/2008/04/28/filtering-sql-injection-from-classic-asp.aspx